# Pyinstaller: No module named 'scipy'

Tags: python, scipy, pyinstaller

I'm trying to use Pyinstaller to bundle a script that uses Scipy (specifically, the [`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) function from scipy.interpolate)

Though it normally works for me fine in Python, I get the error `ImportError: No module named 'scipy'`

I tried it with a simple script that just imports the package

```
import scipy
```

The Pyinstaller code is

```
pyinstaller path/to/code.py
```

I've also tried with hidden-import but no luck.

I know there are other questions out there about importing specific functions from Scipy, but shouldn't I be able to import the main package?

Comment: You didn't even copy the error correctly.

Comment: Your PyInstaller may be using the wrong Python version.

Comment: I'm able to bundle everything if I take out all the scipy references. It just doesn't seem to like that package for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I would install everything carefully with anaconda: first download/install anaconda from www.anaconda.com

then in the anaconda prompt for windows and in a terminal for others:

`conda install scipy`

... (conda install what you need)

`conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller`

and pyinstaller.... (what you need)